# How Datastax implements its async API driver for Cassandra?

Tags: asynchronous, cassandra, datastax, nonblocking, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to convince a coworker of the benefits of using the Session#executeAsync.

However, since we are using the driver from Scala, it would be rather easy to wrap the sync call Session#execute in a Future and that would be all to transform it in an async call. This will be already an improvement because it will give us the opportunity of avoid blocking the current thread (in our case that would represent blocking the threads that handles http requests in play with a huge impact on the number of requests that can be handled concurrently)

I argue that if the work needed to implement an async driver will be wrap it in a Future it won't exist implementations like ReactiveMongo an the Async Api for Cassandra from Datastax.

So,

1. What are the benefits of using the async api?
2. How is the async api implemented in Datastax driver and it what libraries and OS features relies on?
3. What kind of problems were to be solved beyond the asynchronous networks calls? (I mean, implement the async driver must be more than just using java nio)

Answer (score 0):

> How is the async api implemented in Datastax driver and it what libraries and OS features relies on?

Datastax java driver based on [Netty](https://netty.io/) networking framework. Netty itself based on [Event Driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) model. Also for some operating systems  Netty provides native transports to improve performance e.g. [epoll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) for Linux.

> What are the benefits of using the async api?

I'm not a Scala expert but as I know Scala Future based on Threads model (Execution contexts). It means you need to submit a request to another thread to execute  the request asynchronously. For IO tasks you just need request another system and wait response from this system. If you have a big number of requests, all threads in your pool will be busy but will not do anything useful. Thread is a fairly expensive resource and it can be a problem to have thousands threads in the same physical resource. Threads are good for parallel calculation tasks but not for IO tasks.

From other hand Datastax java driver based on Event Driven model (Netty). It means the each request will be submitted in [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) queue. For each iteration of event loop, Netty will define the state of request and will execute handlers associated with this request. 
This approach avoids of memory usage overhead for threads and allows you to perform thousands of IO requests in the same time. But in this case you should define slow or blocking request callbacks in another thread to avoid blocking of event-loop.